# Correct URL for accessing jpg image stored in GCS via Colab

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to adapt the Style Transfer Demo linked below to use my own images:

https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/tf2_arbitrary_image_stylization

In the section where you can try more images, I'm wanting to add images I've stored in a Google Cloud Storage bucket, and have inserted one of those image URIs into the list of images:

```
content_urls = dict(
  portrait_ali='gs://01_bucket-01/portrait-ali-PXL_20220105_233524809.jpg',
  sea_turtle='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/Green_Sea_Turtle_grazing_seagrass.jpg',
  tuebingen='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/00/Tuebingen_Neckarfront.jpg',
  grace_hopper='https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/grace_hopper.jpg',
  )
```

However, I'm getting this error message:

`URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: gs>`

And further down the response, another error:

`Exception: URL fetch failure on gs://01_bucket-01/portrait-ali-PXL_20220105_233524809.jpg: None -- unknown url type: gs`

I also tried adding Colab authentication prior to calling the list of images:

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

# https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects
project_id = 'aiart-01'
!gcloud config set project {project_id}
```

I'm not finding any info on the `gsutil URI`, and much of the `gsutil` info I'm finding is command line-based and not python, so I appreciate any input or guidance regarding how to bring my GCS images into the Tensorflow Colab notebook.

Comment: Can you try this URL of the object`http://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME/OBJECT_NAME`? If it's not public, please create a signed URL for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the TensorFlow Datasets module, tdfs, you can use the gs:// style names to access objects, so long as you're using the "tf.io.gfile" module to load the resources. In the tutorial you linked, it uses "tf.keras.utils.get_file", which I think uses urllib instead, which makes me suspect it won't work. You'd need to use signed URLs (or publicly readable objects) instead, or you could load the resources as a dataset with `tfds.load` instead, in which case gs:// names should work ([instructions on tfds](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/gcs)).

Comment: Thank you. Greatly appreciate the help. However, I'm really struggling with authentication in GCS. I'm going to try just making the bucket public.